# bash shell script heredoc issues

Tags: bash, shell

i want run a bash shell script like this:

> while read file;
>
> do
>
> ```
>    echo $file;
> ```
>
> done << eof
>
> $(ls)
>
> eof;`

it work well in a sample .sh file. but when put this in a function like:

```
function {
    while read file;
    do
        echo $file;
    done << eof 
    $(ls) 
    eof;
}
```

it not work for me.

i dont know how to fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

try un-indenting your eof:

```
function {
    while read file;
    do
        echo $file;
    done << eof 
    $(ls) 
eof;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't indent your heredoc, and your `eof` marker should not have a trailing semicolon

Answer (score 1):

In bash : use `<<-TERMINATION`  if you want it to ignore whitespaces before the `TERMINATION` string (but if you prefer compatibility, use `<<TERMINATION` and have `TERMINATION` alone on a line, and starting at the first column. If the trailing `;` is a problem too, put it on the next line (or put a `: ;` if you prefer)

And give a name to your function : `function myfunction { ... }`  (or, more compatible : `myfunction () { ... }`  )